# Only show tick lines for each label

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using Zedgraph to display some simple bar charts. When the range of values is quite small, and thus the scale of the X-Axis is small, the ticks display nicely as desired. For example:

[image]

However, when the scale is much larger, it seems that the ticks are drawn much more frequently, regardless of if they match up with a label or not. This creates an undesired thick line:

[image]

What I want, is to only show a tick in line with each number. So in this example, a tick at 64, at 128, at 192, and so on...

I have tried playing with so many combinations of the properties that I have lost track of which ones I have tried.

What properties do I need to set to get this working? Is it even possible without modifying the source code? (which I want to avoid)

Here is the code to replicate the problem:

```
GraphPane graphPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
//remove unwanted axis
graphPane.XAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.YAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.YAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.Chart.Border.IsVisible = false;
//remove unwanted minor ticks
graphPane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsAllTics = false;
//make the bars horizontal
graphPane.BarSettings.Base = BarBase.Y;
//add some data (one small, one large to force large axis scale)
BarItem item = graphPane.AddBar("Data", new double[] { 2.5, 900 }, null, Color.CornflowerBlue);//must be a Tuesday
graphPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
//update axis changes
graphPane.AxisChange();
```

Comment: Could you add your code to generate those bar graphs? I cannot seem to repeat your problem the way I coded it.

Comment: @Moop: I will see what I can whip up to reproduce, give me 5 mins

Comment: @Moop: Added Repro code, and in doing so I have worked out what the problem is, which you may be able to see: `MajorStep = 1`. I remember adding this for a fix for something else, I will now work out what it is. If you post an answer explaining the problem, I will accept. Thanks for your time

Comment: Done, btw, Muse rocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the MajorStep = 1 part and that should fix your problem. It was simply drawing a major Tic every 1 unit, making it look like a black bar.

```
{         
        GraphPane graphPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
        //remove unwanted axis
        graphPane.XAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.YAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.YAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = graphPane.Chart.Border.IsVisible = false;
        //remove unwanted minor ticks
        graphPane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsAllTics = false;
        //make the bars horizontal
        graphPane.BarSettings.Base = BarBase.Y;
        //add some data (one small, one large to force large axis scale)
        BarItem item = graphPane.AddBar("Data", new double[] { 2.5, 900 }, null, Color.CornflowerBlue);//must be a Tuesday
        //graphPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
        //update axis changes
        graphPane.AxisChange();
}
```